# Nuxt3 Options API: Why I can't use composables inside setup function?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have Options API component:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "mycomponent",
  async setup() {
    console.log(await useFetch('http://localhost/api/data'));
  },
})
```

When I'm trying to run this code Nuxt3 give me error:

```
500
[nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug. Find out more at `https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#vue-and-nuxt-composables`.
```

Error says I must call this composable from Vue setup function, but I'm already calling this composable from setup function. What's the problem?

Comment: The error probably doesn't come from this component. Please give a minimal reproduction. For example, via https://stackblitz.com/